# How can i Allocate Memory for a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have the following struct:

```
struct Node{
    int *VC;
    Node *Next;
};
```

My goal is to create a linked list of pointers pointing to an `int`

My question is how can i allocate memory for `Node`.
ie

```
int* ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
//code to allocate memory for a new Node n
n->VC = ptr;
n->Next = null;
```

then later i may do:

```
 int *_ptr= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
 //code to allocate memory for a new Node c
 c->VC= _ptr;
 c->Next = null;

 n->Next = c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Node *c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
```

Comment: is it the same as doing:
Node *c = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Comment: @scatman It's better (think of what happens if you later change the type of `c`).

Comment: @Oli: Never forget structure padding. You may waste some memory with it.

Comment: @Akito How are you planing to allocate memory for a struct without "wasting" it for padding ?

Comment: @cnicutar: I agree that there isn't any other way out.

Comment: The above answer is too much of a hack, Is better to write it as timothyqiu wrote below, because it aids standarization, readability and maintenance

Comment: @RedComet: Hack? Standardization? Readablility? Maintenace? The only one I can buy is readability, and not by much.

Comment: @RedComet You mentioned "maintenance". What's to stop someone from changing `struct Node *c` to `struct Node2 *c` *and* forget to change the `malloc` ?

Comment: @RedComet: You should prefer this method; it's robust against someone changing the type.#

Answer (score 5):

Allocating memory for a `struct` is the same as allocating memory for an `int` (in C). Just use `sizeof` to get the size of the struct:

```
struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```